# Inserting consecutive dates into an existing table

Tags: sql, sas

I have an empty table `temp_table` with 2 columns, `date` and `id`. I need to populate it with dates from 01-jan-1990 till 31-Dec-2099 and then convert the date into a string (`yyyymmdd`).

The date format can be any I just need to convert it to  a string at the end

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You should go for a proper `date` format and turn it into a string by using a suitable date format when you apply a select clause. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In the future please read the [ask] section and show what you've tried, what you have and what you want. I've made a random guess below, but it could be entirely wrong. Having a date as a character is in general not a good idea because you can't do duration calculations with character variables.

Comment: For SQL-Server and MySQL as of version 8 a recursive CTE should be helpful. Maybe this page is helpful to you: https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator

Comment: i am sorry I was not clear at all. I am  doing this in impala and  I already tried the while loop but does not seem to work  there

Answer (score 1):

You really do need to try something. A do loop is all that's needed here.

```
    *List of unique ID;
    data ids;
    do id=1 to 5;
        output;
    end;
    run;

    *list of dates;
    data dates;
    do date='01Jan1990'd to '31Dec2099'd;
        output;
    end;
    run;

    *full table;
    proc sql;
    create table want as
    select id, date format=yymmddn8., put(date, yymmddn8.) as date_char
    from ids, dates;
    quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to do everything in a data step

```
data calc_dates;
length date_str $10.;
date='01JAN1990'd;
date_str=put(date,ddmmyy10.);
output;
do while (date<'31DEC2099'd); 
    date=intnx('DAY',date,1);
    date_str=put(date,ddmmyy10.);
    output;
end;
format date date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need dates from 01-01-1990 to 31-12-2099 and then convert to string. below is the query to achieve that:
declare @startdate date
declare @enddate date

set @startdate = '1990-01-01'
set @enddate = '2099-12-31'

select convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(day, Nbr -1 ,@startdate),112) as date1
from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c.object_id) as Nbr
from sys.columns c
)t
where Nbr-1 <= datediff(day,@startdate,@enddate)